# How to fit a superimposed distribution (\eg a Gaussian distribution + a Uniform distribution)

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, inference, fitting

Suppose we have a set of independent observations of a random variable X, which is a Superimposition of two mutual independent random variables (i.e. X = Y + Z), Y follows a uniform distribution, while Z follows a Gaussian distribution.

Can we fit the parameters of these two distributions when only accessing to X?

Comment: The usual word for this "superimposition" is "sum."  Unless the variance of $Y$ is tiny compared to that of $Z,$ you will have great difficulty estimating those variances separately.  Moreover, unless you know the mean of at least one of $Y$ and $Z,$ you cannot estimate their means at all: you can only estimate the sum of their means.

Answer (score 1):

You need the pdf (probability density function) of the sum of independent uniform and Gaussian random variables. That is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227088/pdf-of-the-sum-of-independent-normal-and-uniform-random-variables). You will need to generalize the answer to allow for unknown parameters.

When you have done that, you can estimate parameters by maximum likelihood estimation.